# Is there any elegant ways to convert Int to BigDecimal in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I'm working on my toy project with Kotlin.

While writing code, I feel that those codes are somewhat duplicated and not clean.

```
val a: Int = 1
val a_D: BigDecimal = a.toBigDecimal()
val b_D: BigDecimal = a.toBigDecimal()
```

So, is there any way to avoid those duplication(something like toBigDecimal()) using elegant way?

Comment: You don't need to write the type annotations, so `val a_D = a.toBigDecimal()` is sufficient, and not redundant (because you have to tell Kotlin _somewhere_ that you want a BigDecimal value).

Comment: yep. I knew that type declaration is redundant but what I wanted to point out was toBigDecimal() function call for type conversion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are bothered about having to create the `BigDecimal` over two lines, `BigDecimal` has constructors that take `Int` that you can call directly:

```
 val bigDecimalInt = BigDecimal(1)
```

This is fine for integer values, BUT for floating-point values like `Double` the constructor and `toBigDecimal` actually behave differently. The constructor creates a BigDecimal value of the `Double` value passed in, which will be "incorrect" if that value is not exactly representable in floating-point arithmetic. `toBigDecimal` converts the value to a String and then uses that which gives the "correct" value

```
val doubleNum:Double = 0.1
println(doubleNum.toBigDecimal()) // prints 0.1

val bigDecimal:BigDecimal = BigDecimal(0.1)
println(bigDecimal)               // prints 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

If none of that makes sense, you probably need to read about Floating Point Arithmetic, this is a common problem affecting all/most programming languages

So `toBigDecimal` is a safer option

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have to adapt to kotlin development!

Comment: To be fair, I think all the above applies to using BigDecimal in Java too :-)